# service-connector tunnel opening fails

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm trying to connect to a running ELK instance from my local computer using the service-connector as described here:
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/elk.html#service-connector

EDIT: I do first log into the cloud from the command line with `cf login`.

The tunnel fails to open when using the command: `cf sc 30000 <kibanaUrl>` (I retrieve the kibanaUrl from the environement variables).

The output error message is:

`Creating tunnel ...
Server domain: scapp.io
FAILED
dial tcp 194.209.246.110:443: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because
the target machine actively refused it.`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems an firewall issue. Is the port 443 open on the destination host for communication? A good test to check the port is: telnet 194.209.246.110:443  (refused = blocked  or connected=open) othewise curl -i 134.168.24.230:3306 (Connection: keep-alive= open).

Comment: The destination host is the cloud into which I'm logged in (I assume the host and port come from the kibanaUrl) and I have no control over the firewalls between my computer and the cloud. Since the cloud login works, why shouldn't this?

Comment: As mentioned at link https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector/. If you are working behind a corporate proxy, set the http_proxy environment variable, e.g. http_proxy=proxy.corproot.net:8079 . For more information type cf service-connector -h in the prompt.

Comment: I did set the proxy! How else could I have login into the cloud?

Comment: Test with an open Wifi-Network (i.e. Free_Swisscom_Office)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it in my environments (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04): It seems you have set the `https_proxy` environment variable but not the `http_proxy` environment variable (as RoccoE mentioned). I guess, if you set also the `http_proxy` variable, it will work.

> e.g. for windows: set http_proxy=proxy.corproot.net:8079
>
> e.g. for linux: export http_proxy=proxy.corproot.net:8079